# PHP - Checking whether a string exists in an entire array?

Tags: php, arrays, strpos

Basic array question:

```
$string = "The quick brown cat";

$check1 = "apple";
$check2 = "ball";
$check3 = "cat";

if ( (stripos($string, $check1) === false) ||
     (stripos($string, $check2) === false) ||
     (stripos($string, $check3) === false)
   ) {
   echo "Fail";
}
```

How do I condense the above using an array ($check[])?

Thanks!

Comment: @RC : you mean checking if they are all there in string? or at least one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should still use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
$checks = array('apple', 'ball', 'cat');
foreach($checks as $c){
  if(strpos($string, $c) === false){
    echo "Fail";
    break;
  }
}
```

### benchmarks: strpos() wins

```
<?php

function benchmark($callback){
  echo sprintf('%-30s: ', $callback);
  $t = microtime(true);
  foreach(range(1, 10000) as $n){
    call_user_func($callback);
  }
  echo (microtime(true)-$t)."\n";
}

function smotchkkiss_strpos(){
  $string = "The quick brown cat";
  $checks = array('apple', 'ball', 'cat');
  foreach($checks as $c){
    if(strpos($string, $c) === false){
      break;
    }
  }
}

function konforce_preg_match(){
  $string = "The quick brown cat";
  preg_match('/apple|ball|cat/i', $string);
}

function konforce_preg_match_implode(){
  $string = "The quick brown cat";
  $checks = array('apple', 'ball', 'cat');
  preg_match('/'.implode('|', $checks).'/i', $string);
}


benchmark('smotchkkiss_strpos');
benchmark('konforce_preg_match');
benchmark('konforce_preg_match_implode');

# output
# smotchkkiss_strpos            : 0.020166158676147
# konforce_preg_match           : 0.032760858535767
# konforce_preg_match_implode   : 0.045573949813843

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
if (preg_match('/apple|ball|cat/i', $string)) ...
```

Or

```
if (preg_match('/'.implode('|', $check).'/i', $string)) ...
```

Comment: PS. This only checks for any single element. If you are looking for all, it won't be helpful.